Applied to renew passport, forgot to send passport card
Mailed in a passport book to be renewed and requested a new passport book and a new passport card.  Unfortunately, forgot that I already had a passport card so did not include that and did not fill in that number of the DS-82.  Got a letter back from department of state saying "you did not include your passport card, send us your passport card, your proof of citizenship documents are being returned to you, we'll hold on to your fees, you have 90 days."
There are instructions for a) if I still have the passport card (which I do) or b) if it was lost but they are not clear.  I'll contact the department of state but I expect that to be a difficult process.  If anyone has had a similar experience, what's actually supposed to happen?  Am I supposed to wait for my old passport book to arrive back then send it along with a copy of the letter I received and the passport card back to the state department?  I don't want to sit around waiting for the passport book to arrive if they're not actually sending it but I don't want to get into a "mail tag" situation where I send one thing at a time and they keep sending it back.

Can you clarify - what nationality are you, and where are you resident? This is important to help us provide an answer.

@RoryAlsop United states.  I thought the tags would be sufficient.

It was to gain clarity that you are a US citizen, resident in the US, renewing a US passport, because there are other possibilities :-)

Could you include the full and exact text of the instructions you received, and explain what part is not clear?
